Computing probabilities given overlapping intervals?
Suppose that you use an item response theory model to infer student ability and question difficulty on some training set. Now, we want to use this data for the purpose of dynamic testing where student ability and question difficulty are in the same latent parameter.
Let's suppose that a given student is asked two questions, the first in red and the second in blue. The first determines that there's a 70% chance that the student's ability is greater than -0.5 on this latent parameter space. The second question determines that there's a 30% chance that the student's ability is above 0.5 (same space.)
How should the probabilities of each bucket be computed? (-inf, -0.5), [-0.5, 0.5], (0.5, inf)

Edit: Used a likelihood product and then divided by sum to ensure that probability mass sums to 1.0


This is usually done in a Bayesian way. You start with a prior that is normal (0, 1) and then multiply by the likelihood. It doesn't matter what order you multiply in - and then you end up with a posterior that you can use to calculate the probabilities. Each time you ask another question, you update the posterior.

@JeremyMiles, this is interesting! Would you be able to add more detail or link a reference in an answer?

Item response theory (IRT) scoring often uses Expected A Posteriori (EAP) scoring. This is a Bayesian method where a prior distribution is updated based on information that is gained from the way that a person answers a question.
The first step (which the question misses) is what the distribution looks like when we have no information. If we have no information about a person's score, then their expected distribution of scores is normal, with mean = 0 and sd = 1.  This is the prior.
When a person answers a question, you get some information, and you use this to update the prior, to get the posterior. You keep doing this every time you get information about another question (and it doesn't matter what order you present the questions).
When you have the final distribution, you can calculate these probabilities.
The way that you have answered the question (in the question) ignores the prior distribution. But it is the correct approach.
There's more information here: Chapman, R. Expected a posteriori scoring in PROMIS®. J Patient Rep Outcomes 6, 59 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1186/s41687-022-00464-9
